# React Native Notification Websockets v/s Firestore listener v/s SSE

Tags: firebase, react-native, websocket, google-cloud-firestore, server-sent-events

I am developing a mobile app using react native. My backend application is developed using springboot. My app talks to backend using REST.
I want to send some notification to the user of the app from my backend (via one of the options mentioned below). This cannot be a Push Notification as user can disable push notification for my app.
 On recieveing this notification the app will communicate with backend using rest api's to fetch more details and complete the transaction.

I want to know what would be a better strategy to send a notification for the user.

1. Websockets
2. Using Firestore event listener(since I am already using Firebase to send Push Notitification for users who have enabled it)
3. SSE(server sent events)
4. Periodic polling from the app to backend (I do not like this approach)

I know this is a bit broad topic. I just need some pointers as to which option is better in terms of fault tolerance, performance and scalability.
I want to know how this is generally implemented. I am new to app development.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion Firebase is the best option for mobile apps, websocket can be be closed by android and are not always controllable. They also consume a lot of energy which can drain phone battery.

Comment: Yep I suggest the second option

Answer (score 1):

I have the same requirements for a project where need to send notification regardless of using a third party application like Firebase. How I achieve this I will share with you may be it will help you.

> **Backend** -> ASP.NET Core
>
> **Real time communication** -> SignalR Core
>
> **Protocols** -> Websocket, Server sent events, Long Pooling
>
> **RN Package** -> react-native-push-notification

It was completely fine except for one drawback that it will only communicate and send push notification when app is running (background/foreground) I think it depend on your situation and your requirement if your app is continuously will in the main app this will work for you otherwise you need to use the third-party service like Firebase and it will also work when your app is not running just need to be connected with the internet.